# jQuery - Trigger mouseover only if the event is long enough

Tags: jquery, ajax

On a page I have a calendar, moving the cursor on the days an AJAX call is sent to the server to retrieve the events of the day. The events are then listed into a div aside the calendar.
This works correctly.

The problem is: if the cursor is on a day which is not positioned along a side of the calendar, but it is internal, it is impossible to move the cursor away from the calendar without to trigger another call which shows the events for another day.
This is because the "mouseover" event is triggered instantly as the cursor moves on other days.
What I need is to trigger the jQuery function only if the cursor stays few time (let's say 500ms) on the day, not only if it just passes on it.
So, is it possible to say to jQuery: "trigger the function if the mouseove lasts at least 500ms, if not, do nothing"?

My jQuery function at the moment is

```
$('div#eventi-home').on('mouseover', 'li.calday', function() {  
    var $li = $(this),  
    form_data = {  
        day: $li.data('giorno'),  
        month: $li.data('mese'),  
        year: $li.data('anno')  
    };  

    $.ajax({  
        url: "<?php echo base_url('home/events_of_the_day/') ?>",  
        type: 'POST',  
        data: form_data,  
        success: function(msg) {  
            $('div#events-of-the-day').html(msg);  
        }  
    });  
});
```

And a day has this code

```
<li class="calday" data-giorno="14" data-mese="11" data-anno="2013" >14</li>
```

How do I have to change my function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hoverIntent` plugin is perfect for this:

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

---

```
$('div#eventi-home li.calday').hoverIntent(function() {  
    var $li = $(this),  
    form_data = {  
        day: $li.data('giorno'),  
        month: $li.data('mese'),  
        year: $li.data('anno')  
    };  

    $.ajax({  
        url: "<?php echo base_url('home/events_of_the_day/') ?>",  
        type: 'POST',  
        data: form_data,  
        success: function(msg) {  
            $('div#events-of-the-day').html(msg);  
        }  
    });  
}, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a timeout:

```
$('div#eventi-home').on('mouseover mouseout', 'li.calday', function (e) {
    clearTimeout(window.timeout);
    if (e.type === "mouseout") return;
    window.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        //CODE HERE...
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: With this solution, the function was always triggered, in addition the data returned from the ajax call were not shown on the page.

Comment: You are righe, the problem was the variables' scope, I put them inside the setTimeout(function...
I've put them after the if (e.type... and now also your solution works.
Thank you too.